# Limiting max character output in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii

I am having trouble formatting the output of this loop to only have 15 characters per line. Can someone please help?

```
public class ASCII {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int ascii = 43; ascii <= 120; ascii++) {
        System.out.print((char)ascii + "  ");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Keep track of how many character you've printed, and when it hits 15, print a new line.

Comment: You could just insert this before your printout: `if(ascii-43 % 15 == 0) { System.out.println(); }`. But you would get an empty line at the start of your program. If you can't stand that, choose one of the more complex solutions given by others.

Comment: @Gendarme That's a nice solution, but you would need to subtract 42 from ascii and enclose it in parenthesis since the modulus has higher precedence than subtraction. Example:  `if ((ascii - 42) % 15 == 0)`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I didn't know that it had higher precedence. And of course it should be 42 instead of 43. I'm stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish that:

```
for (int ascii = 43, i = 1; ascii <= 120; ascii++) {
     System.out.print((char)ascii + "  ");

     if (i++ % 15 == 0)
     {
          System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Mainly I was just confused about what type of loop would be compatible as if tried the for loop with the if loop before and it was showing an error and your solution cleared it up!

Comment: @AvenNova No problem!